# Best way to filter on data belonging to the logged in user (Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django

First of all; I'm fairly new to Django.

Right now, I'm trying to create a very simple webpage with links (just to learn). The idea right now is, that a user (which is logged in) can add links to the database/model, and only see the links of which he has added.

I'm strugling to figure out what the best practice is for that - is it to store the `user.username` in the model, and then make a `.filter(username=user)` each time or..? I would assume Django has some (faster way) of handling this.

I have the following

`models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class links(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    #user = <something_here>
```

`views.py`

```py
def add_link(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = add_link_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, "Link is added!")
            form.save()
            return redirect("my_links")
    else:
        form = add_link_form()

    context = {
        "links":links.objects.all(),
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, "django_project/my_links.html",context=context)
```

`my_links.html`

```py
{% extends "django_project/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{form|crispy}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add link</button>
        </div>
    </form>

  {% for l in links%}

    {{l.link}}

    {% endfor%}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You can use [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) :  `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, ...) `

Comment: With a ForeignKey you can access a users's links with `user.links_set.all()`. (And you should rename the class `links` to `Link` according to python/django naming conventions.

Comment: Say I have more fields (date and browser), do I then need to call `user.date_set.all()` and `user.browser_set.all()`? I.e if I have many fields that is a lot of manual code

Answer (score 0):

You can define Link as:

```py
class Link(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="links")
```

where, when adding you could do:

`logged_in_user.links.create(...)`

or if adding an already existing link:

`logged_in_user.links.add(link)`

or if you know that links will forever remain as as strings without any other data related to it, and you use postgresql as your DB, you could add this field to the user model:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class UserModel(models.Model):
    ...
    links = ArrayField(models.URLField(), default=list)
```

and when adding, treat it exactly as you would do with an array:

```py
logged_in_user.links.append("google.com")
logged_in_user.save()
```

---

Both of these approaches, in essence, provide you a filtered list when calling `logged_in_user.links`, but in the first case it is a queryset of `Link` objects, whereas the second is an array of strings.

Comment: How is it then used to filter in the template? Does Django handle it by it self in some way or ..?